# Blazor Webassembly JWT Authorization first steps

Tags: authentication, jwt, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have created a small .NET 5.0 Web API where a users can register/login to create/add/delete notes. The API is working fine, after the login I receive the JWT token in the response back.

Now I want to create a Blazor Webassembly website which will communicate with the API.
The problem I have is that I don't know where to start and what do I need to get the web page take the Token from the response and how to work with it to be authorized when doing API calls.

In the API i have used the IHttppAccesor to get access to the user data from the JWT token, is it similar to work with the token for the authorization.

Any suggestions what to use or where to start would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you not done a search online? There’s plenty of tutorials on how to do this

Comment: Good approach is to generate asp.net core hosted blazor app with authorization by Visual studio and study that code.